# Prove that number of $(A, B, C)$ with $A ∩ B ∩ C = \emptyset$, $A ∩ B \ne \emptyset$, $B ∩ C \ne \emptyset$ is $7^n − 2\cdot6^n + 5^n$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Prove that the number of triples $(A, B, C)$ where $A, B, C$ are subsets
>   of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ such that $A ∩ B ∩ C = \emptyset$, $A ∩ B \ne \emptyset$, $B ∩ C \ne \emptyset$ is $7^n − 2\cdot6^n + 5^n$.

I need some help with this problem. It is from a [$2004$ RMO paper](http://www.isical.ac.in/~rmo/rmo04.pdf).

A hint or two would suffice - please do *not* give me a complete, cut-and-dried answer :)

(Something tells me that we can use generating functions for this. Is it so?)

Comment: From the form of the solution seems it may be related to inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: Try induction on $n$

Comment: esob onko kore kono lav nei ahammok

Comment: ...keno lav nei?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Treat your sets element-wise, that is, for example, via their characteristic functions or vectors $\{0,1\}^n$ of dimension $n$.
- $A \cap B \cap C$ would say that $\forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}.\ A_i = 0 \lor B_i = 0 \lor C_i = 0$. That implies $7$ possibilities for each coordinate, and $7^n$ possibilities in total with $A \cap B \cap C = \varnothing$ only.
- $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$ rules out the possibility of $A_i = 0 \lor B_i = 0$ forall $i$, that is, $\neg\Big(\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}.\ A_i = 0 \lor B_i = 0\Big)$ or equivalently $\exists i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}.\ A_i = 1 \land B_i = 1$.
- $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$ and $B \cap C \neq \varnothing$ have a common non-empty intersection, so according to [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we need to add it, hence the $+5^n$ term.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I'm sure that you intend to help, but the language is a *bit* too advanced for me. What is a characteristic function?

Comment: I understood the $7^n$ part, and the third point. What about the last point?

Comment: In this context the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) could also be called an [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question about the last point. Which particular fragment is hard for you? Do you know what is inclusion-exclusion principle (e.g. have you read the Wikipedia article)?

Comment: Yes, I know the inclusion-exclusion principle. Could you explain why the last point refers to $5^n$? What I meant is that a slightly more detailed answer would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I just had my 'aha!' moment :)